# ant eclipse: package org.apache.log4j does not exist

Tags: eclipse, ant, junit, compiler-errors, log4j

I'm a java-greenhorn trying to compile my project via ant, but nothing's working.
So, in my class I'm using `log4j.jar` and `import junit`. Everything's in Eclipse, either Ant.
Here is the build.xml file:

```
    <path id="master-classpath">
    <pathelement path="D:\.a lot of folders..\junit.jar"/>
    <!--<pathelement path="D:\...\log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>    --> 
    <fileset dir="D:\apache-log4j-1.2.17">
            <include name="log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="${buildSrc}"/>
</path>
```

And `compile` block:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src1}" destdir="${buildSrc}"/>
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src2}" destdir="${buildSrc}"/>
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${test}" destdir="${buildTest}">
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        </javac>
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" classpath="${buildSrc}"/>
    </target>
```

I've also tried some different approaches, like making the same in the javac-task, using property, etc, to no success. Could you please, identify my mistake and help deal with it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${test}" destdir="${buildTest}">
    <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
 </javac>
```

should work.  As should "classpathref" as an attribute on javac itself.

Possibilities:

1. Typo in folder name
2. Typo in file name
3. D drive isn't mapped

Comment: maybe 3rd variant.. thank You. everything worked correctly when i added jars in /lib/ext folder. not the best way to solve the problem, but it works.